# How do I kill the skeletons located in The Catacombs?

Tags: dark-souls

No matter how many times I kill the skeletons found in the catacombs, they always come back to life. To say the least it is very annoying.

[image]

Is there anyway to prevent them from coming back to life?

Comment: Weakness: falling

Comment: [Blacksmith Andre](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/andre-of-astora) hints at it if you talk to him enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways to kill the skeletons:

- Kill the Necromancer reviving them. There are several Necromancers located in the catacombs (See below screenshot) which are responsible for the skeletons coming back to life. If you kill a Necromancer the skeletons in his area will stop reviving after you kill them. The Necromancer will not re-spawn after you kill him.

  (image source: taken from this video):

[image]

- Another way to ensure the skeletons stay dead, regardless of whether or not the Necromancer is still alive, is to kill them using a Divine weapon.

Answer (score 3):

Lure them to a pit and kick them into pit. That will do the job.

Comment: This only really works for the first couple skeletons and the first pit. IIRC, kicking skeltons off other ledges in the catacombs simply puts them in different part of the level making you fight them later.

Answer (score -3):

use the combustion spell and end their lives with epic roast's

Comment: Does this stop them from coming back? I don't believe it does.